# Maximize the area of a triangle that you build out of the tangents of $x^2$ for x $\epsilon [0,1]$ the line x = 1 and the x axis

Tags: calculus

$h(x) = x^2$  x $\epsilon$ [0,1]

1.) For x0 $\epsilon$ [0,1] is $tx0$ for the function h at the position x0. What is the function for the tangents?

2.) The tangent $tx0$ from above constructs with the x axis and the line x = 1 a triangle. For which value of x0 has this triangle the biggest area?

How do I solve this problem?

1.) Should be easy. It would be $h'(x) = 2x$

2.) I have some problems to understand what they mean with 'a line' and x = 1, I assume that it would be g(x) = 1.

I know how to calculate the area of a triangle $(x+y)/2$ 
I also know that the y is fixed because of $g(x) = 1$. So in order to get the maximum area I would need to make $x$ as large as possible.

I also know that x0 has to be bigger than 0 because if it is zero it can't build a triangle.

And the formula for a line is $y = m*x + b$

I just tried out some values:

h'(1) = 2*1 = 2, so with $y = m*x + b$ I think $1 = 2*x + 1$

So it cuts the $g(x)$ at x0 = 1 and the x-axis at x=0, which would give me an area of $(1 + 1)/2 = 1$

Then I tried it at

$h'(1/2) = 2*1/2 = 1$

$1 = x + (1/2)^2 => 1 = x + 1/4 => x = 3/4$, so it cuts the y axis at $x = 3/4$, and because it's a line it should cut the x axis at $-3/4$ which would make the triangle $(6/4 + 1)/2$ which is bigger.

So my assumption now is to make x0 as close as possible to 0 as I can get. Maybe I need to use a limit?

It's very likely that I have made a mistake above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of the tangent at $(x_0,y_0),\enspace y_0=x_0^ 2$, is:
$$y=2x_0 x-x_0^2.$$
Its $x$-intercept  is $\bigl(\frac{x_0} 2,0\bigr)$ and the triangle is right-angled thus its area is
$$\frac 12y_0\cdot \frac{x_0}2=\frac 14x_0^3.$$
As this is an increasing function, the area is maximal for $x_0=1$.

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake in your first step. The tangent line is given by

$$y-f(x_0)=2x_0(x-x_0)\Rightarrow y=2x_0 x-x_0^2$$

Then for the second part, you will need to figure out the intersection of this line with the lines $x=1$ and $x$-axis, then use the triangle area formula.

By the way, you should format your problem better to make it more understandable.